# Nested shorthand if bug

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have this code below using nested shorthand if:

```php
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->type = 'regular';
$foo->group_one = 1;
$foo->group_two = 2;

$group_id = $foo->type == 'regular' ? $foo->group_one : $foo->type == 'agent' ? $foo->group_two : null;

var_dump($group_id);
```

I expected the value to be `1`. Why the value of `$group_id` is `2`?

Comment: ternary should make code easier to read - not harder

Comment: I agree, but the bug persists